# Thymeleaf with SpringBoot - how to loop model and delete?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using SpringBoot with Thymeleaf to build a trivial example to help me learn the two technologies.

I am basing my example on [THIS GUIDE](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

The entity is a Greeting which has an Id and a Content.

I create the Greeting just fine, and I can list all the Greetings I've created.

I then wanted to add a delete option against each Greeting in the list page.  When clicking delete, I want the object to be deleted and the list page served up again.

Alas, when I load the list page I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'greeting' available as request attribute

**Controller and respository objects**

```
    @Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    GreetingRepo gr;

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String greetingsForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greetings", gr.findAll());
        return "greeting/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/delete", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteGreeting(@ModelAttribute("greeting") Greeting greeting) {
        gr.delete(greeting);
        return "redirect:/greeting/list";
    }


}

@RepositoryRestResource
interface GreetingRepo extends JpaRepository<Greeting, Long> {

}
```

**List.html page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <div th:each="greeting : ${greetings}">
        <p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
        <p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting/delete}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{content}"/>
            <input type="Submit" value="Delete"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <a href="/greeting/add">Add another</a>
    <a href="/greeting/list">Show All</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate a push in the right direction here :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss this line .

```
model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting/list", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String greetingsForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
    model.addAttribute("greetings", gr.findAll());
    return "greeting/list";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hasitha, this got past the error, however, the Greeting object isn't instantiated when it arrives in the delete method of the controller.  I.e. the id is always 0 despite what I click on.

Also, I'm curious why I'd need to add an empty object to the model, when the real object is already in the model?  I.e. the 'greeting**s**' object is a list containing all the 'greeting' objects.  I thought I'd be able to use the current iteration (greeting) variable in the nested delete form?

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to use a `form` to `delete` the greeting you can do it very easily with this approach. hide the `id` of the `greeting` within the `url`. so you dont need to use a `form` and `hidden tags`. and `annotate` the `controller` method with following approach, to accept `incoming id` of the `greeting`.
replace the current `form` with given `html` code and `replace` the `delete` method in the `controller` as well.

```
    <a th:href="@{/greeting/{id}/delete(id=${greeting.id})}" th:text="delete"></a>

         @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/{id}/delete",method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String deleteGreeting(@PathVariable int id) {
            gr.delete(id);
            return "redirect:/greeting/list";
        }
```

edit:- since you need the object to be present within the controller
you can use findOne method to fetch the object from the given id.check out the following example.

```
    <a th:href="@{/greeting/{id}/edit(id=${greeting.id})}" th:text="edit"></a>

    @RequestMapping(value="/greeting/{id}/edit",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Edit(@PathVariable int id){
    greeting greetingob = gr.findOne(id);
    return "edit";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Priyamal, I changed
`@RequestMapping(value="/{id}/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)`
to
`@RequestMapping(value="/greeting/{id}/delete", method=RequestMethod.GET)`

and it works.  However, I was really after a button and example showing how to pass the object into the method in such a scenario.  My next step was to do edit of the object hence why I'm interested in this.

Comment: whats the output of `<p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />` this line in the view. is it `0` ?.

Comment: In my example, (if I comment out the 'form' so that it will run), the output would be like: 

`id: 6`

Comment: Confused, in my previous comment I said I already did that change.  This is how I got your hyperlink suggestion to work.  I'm after a button and passing the object to the controller.

Comment: you can use `findOne` method and get the object. inside the controller.

Comment: Thanks Priyamal, no doubt that will work.  However, I'm really trying to get to the bottom of how to pass the *actual* object to the controller method in my question.